# Dynamic and custom Urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working at my first Django REST Api and I have a question about the routing.

I have a JSON and the short form looks like this:

```
{
      "name": "Summer Festival",
      "date": "2020-01-05",
      "deadline": "2020-01-01",
      "address": "Fantasy Road 50",
      "postcode": 12346,
      "location": "New York",
      (...)
}
```

I use this ViewSet:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

and this serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = "__all__"
```

My urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("events", views.EventViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path(
        'events/location=<str:address>&from=<str:from>&to=<str:to>',
         views.EventViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"})),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

The scenario:

On my frontend is a form where you can pick your postcode and a date range.
When the user just inserts his postcode he gets all events up today and the url should look like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/postcode=12345

When the user picks a from date and postcode it should like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/postcode=12345&from=2019-01-01

With a daterange + postcode like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/postcode=12345&from=2019-01-01&to=2019-02-01

The url should be dynamically build.
The second path in my urls.py code snippet is a workaround but this urls isn't dynamically created. My first idea was to just set the values null but the result is just a large url with no information.

I already tried to work with the lookup field but you just can use it with a single value.

Is there another builtin django or django rest approach to achieve this dynamic url with dynamic query parameters?

Comment: Have you looked into django-filter? It would put all of those filtering options into the querystring, which is likely where they belong. Attempting to do it in the relative path of the url seems painful.

Comment: Your urls for filtering are wrong. They should be like this: `/events/?postcode=12345` (with the question mark!!). That way `postcode` is a **query parameter** which is in `request.GET` without even having to create new urls.

Comment: No I never heard of it before. I though there is an option within Django Rest because the router handles the urls: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: @dirkgroten Ah alright I didn't know that! I'll check it and hope that this might solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Django take help of URL dispatchers to router request to appropriate view.
- Django provide both(static and dynamic) options for URL.
- In django if you want to generate dynamic URL you take help of **regular expression**
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions